How to fix an internal server error when authenticating with Auth.js (next-auth v5)
In my Next.js project, I want to add authentication with next-auth@5 -beta. When I sign in using the google account, it gives 500 internal server error.(http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=Configuration).
src/auth.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),

    ],
    secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET
})

src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
import { handlers } from "@/auth"
export const { GET, POST } = handlers

src/app/page.js
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { auth } from "@/auth";
export default async function Home() {
  const session = await auth();
  console.log(session)

  if (!session) redirect("/api/auth/signin")
  return (
    <div>
      HOMEPAGE
    </div>
  );
}


src/app/layout.js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}



i am watching the doc page and i see some routes configuration differences. Did you try to use dynamic rotues as described?
For istance:

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js


I am using next auth v5, this docs is for next auth v4.
